# Color scheme is lost on shell change

Tags: bash, shell, colors

My default login shell is `ksh` which shows my default color scheme which I set via putty.
But when I change my shell to `bash` my color scheme is lost.

Is there a way to retain the color scheme?

EDIT:

In order to set colors of my console window via putty , I used this link : http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Desert_color_scheme_with_Vim_in_PuTTY

Comment: How exactly are you setting the scheme using putty? What colors are you referring to?

Comment: I used this link to change color scheme for console screen via putty: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Desert_color_scheme_with_Vim_in_PuTTY

Comment: Bash can set its own colors which are probably overriding your settings. Could you post your `~/.bashrc` file? ALso check for `~/.Xresources`.

Comment: What is colorized on your console? `ls` output? In that case you need to `eval $(dircolors)` and set up an alias for `ls=ls --color=auto`. See what you have in `/etc/ksh.kshrc` wrt this and copy it to your `.bashrc` or to `/etc/bashrc`.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't actually a way to do it.  When you set the colors in Putty's settings it sends them as a command to the currently enabled shell.  Once you change the shell it drops the colors (since they weren't saved anywhere) and you get the new shell's settings.

My suggestion would be to find the colors you like and then put them into your shells' config files.  Then Putty won't need to send the files and you won't have to worry about dropping colors as you switch between them.

Comment: Yep. putty doesn't have any way to tell when you switch shells.

Answer (score 0):

I think colors for bash are set in ~/.bashrc, so I imagine the color scheme for ksh is set in ~/.kshrc. Just a guess.

Comment: I am setting my color scheme via putty, so profile doesn't have any settings.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to the `~/.bashrc` file in your home folder.

```sh
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi
```